# Open a browser, go to a website and login batch script

Tags: vbscript

I would like to make a batch script for auto-logging to a website using ie, chrome, or firefox on windows 10.

I already have a code, but it's not working properly as I want: right after I double-click the file I must manually click on browser window after the browser starts and there's some problem with timing which I don't how to solve.

Hope I will find a solution here with your help.

```
My code:
Const strURL = "https://www.raise.com/user/sign_in"
Const strID = "testinsl@gmail.com"
Const strPswd = "1q2w3e4r5t!"

Set objIE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate2 strURL

Do While objIE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys strID
WScript.Sleep 100
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
objShell.SendKeys strPswd
WScript.Sleep 100
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: How is this linked to tag [tag:batch-file]??

Comment: What is the issue you are getting? I ran the code and it worked fine.